# How to assign a delegate with a condition in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a delegate:

```
$('body').delegate('li.doc-tab', 'click', function (event) { 
     //Stuff
});
```

This works perfectly for li.doc-tabs but there is a condition

I would like to add which is if the li has an id of

```
doc-tab-selected
```

Is it possible to negate an li if it has this id even though it still has the specified class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
$('body').delegate('li.doc-tab:not(#doc-tab-selected)', 'click', function (event) { 
     //Stuff
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean it should not apply when the li has an ID of doc-tab-selected? If so, you can use [not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
'li.doc-tab:not(#doc-tab-selected)'
```